# Permutations of the first $n$ positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, integers

What is the largest *n* such that there exists a permutation of the first *n* positive integers in which no two consecutive terms share any digit?

Comment: I assume you mean in base 10, right?  Otherwise consider the permutation of $n!$ to be written in base $n$ and you have all digits distinct, trivially satisfying your condition.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Indeed, base 10.

Comment: 7654321 has 5040 numbers with all those digits but only $3^7$ possible neighbours.